# <c:if test> seems to always evaluate true in JSF2 Facelets

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, facelets

I am using JSF2 on Facelets.

I define an `<ui:param>` in a page:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/ui.xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
  <ui:param name="title" value="OnAir WebDemo" />
  ...
</ui:composition>
```

in the `ui.xhtml` template I have:

```
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
>
  <c:if test="#{not empty title}">
    <h1>#{title}</h1>
  </c:if>
</html>
```

However, `<c:if test>` seems to always evaluate `true`, also if the `<ui:param>` is not specified. How can I change the code so that `<c:if test>` will actually evaluate `false` when the `<ui:param>` is not specified?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The XML namespace is invalid. It should be

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

Yes, astonishingly with the `/jsp` part in the URI! The one without `/jsp` works only in Facelets 1.x for JSF 1.x. If you have checked the generated HTML output in the webbrowser, you should have noticed as well that the `<c:if>` is left unparsed in the HTML output.

---

That said, you should prefer JSF components over JSTL tags, unless technically impossible (i.e. when you actually want to control the *building* of the view, not *rendering* of the view). The `h:panelGroup` as you found out yourself is a good candidate, however the `ui:fragment` is a nicer choice since it has less overhead.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty title}">
    <h1>#{title}</h1>
</ui:fragment>
```

Note that due to a mistake of the JSF guys in the `<ui:fragment>` tag definition file of the initial JSF 2.0 version, Netbeans will jerk that the tag doesn't support the `rendered` attribute, but this is untrue. It certainly supports it. It has been fixed in JSF 2.1 tag definition.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
- [Alternative to ui:fragment in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/)
- [Conditional rendering of non-JSF components (plain vanilla HTML and template text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946985/the-right-way-to-conditional-rendering-of-non-jsf-components)

Comment: I've been using `h:panelGroup` just for its `rendered` attribute for _years_; I didn't know about `ui:fragment`! This substantially improves performance and reduces the amount of generated HTML in places where I conditionally render things in `ui:repeat`s over large collections. Thanks! I learn something new with every one of your answers, @BalusC.

Comment: @Nick: you're welcome. Note that `<h:panelGroup>` already effectively renders nothing when there are no attributes specified which should end up in the HTML, such as `id`. But indeed, the `<ui:fragment>` saves *some* `UIComponent` encoding overhead (and is IMHO more self-documenting for the sole purpose).

Comment: Odd, I could have sworn that I saw `<h:panelGroup>` rendering an empty `<span>` tag in the html, even when its only attribute is a `rendered` that evaluates to false, but I'm not seeing it now...

Comment: i attempted to add this to the top of my index.xhtml file, but now I receive a java.lang.NullPointerException error with really not much other info. Do you know why this would happen?

Answer (score 3):

Well,

I used `rendered` instead, like this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{title!=null}">

                <h1>#{title}</h1>

        </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Haven't tried it :-) Was curious about what's the disatvantage or why is it considered a bad practice. Will update if I can try it out.

Comment: I think that it was voted down since !null doesn't check empty.