# ui:fragment rendered attribute not working after upgrading Facelets to JSF 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, fragment

I am upgrading a project from JSF1.2/Facelets1.1 to JSF2.1 with built in facelets.  The following no longer works and I don't know why.  Both ui:fragments apparently evaluate to true, and both the link version and the plain text version are rendered:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{rootcauseid ne rc.id}">
    <a href="#{request.contextPath}/viewrootcause.jsf?rootcausenum=#{rc.id}">Root Cause #{rcRowCounter + 1}</a>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{rootcauseid eq rc.id}">
    <h:outputText value="Root Cause #{rcRowCounter + 1}"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

The following does work, so I have a valid workaround.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{rootcauseid ne rc.id}">
    <a href="#{request.contextPath}/viewrootcause.jsf?rootcausenum=#{rc.id}">Root Cause #{rcRowCounter + 1}</a>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:outputText value="Root Cause #{rcRowCounter + 1}"
    rendered="#{rootcauseid eq rc.id}"/>
```

But why doesn't the ui:fragment version work?  What has changed about Facelets and JSF that would make a difference?  Is "ui:fragment rendered='...'" no longer a valid idiom?

Comment: It should work fine to my knowledge. Try to debug calculation of rendered. How do you declare namespace for ui prefix?

Comment: The UI prefix is defined as:
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

Answer (score -1):

According to the specification, ui:fragment has only id and binding attributes.

Comment: This is not true. This was a documentary bug. It was always been in Facelets, but only fixed in the tag documentation since JSF 2.1. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/3714063#3714063 The concrete problem is caused by a change in the lifecycle of the `<ui:fragment>` tag in JSF 2.1 as opposed to Facelets 1.x and 2.0.

Comment: BalusC, great information.  If you have any more information on the lifecycle changes in <ui:fragment> and post that as an answer, I'll happily "accept" that response.