# "rendered" attribute in "ui:fragment"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I want to use the `rendered` attribute in a `ui:fragment` to conditionally render a `span` element in my JSF 2.2 facelet. The [JSF 2.2 documentation of ui:fragment](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/fragment.html) lists `rendered` as an allowed attribute. I am using MyFaces 2.2.12 as JSF implementation, however, and the [MyFaces 2.2 documentation of ui:fragment](https://myfaces.apache.org/core22/myfaces-impl/tlddoc-facelets/ui/fragment.html) does *not* list `rendered` as a valid attribute.

I tried using `rendered` anyway, and it worked. However, my IDE - IntelliJ - rightly highlights the `rendered` attribute as an error and tells me it is not allowed in the `ui:fragment` element.

I saw a response in [ui:fragment rendered attribute not working after upgrading Facelets to JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775659/uifragment-rendered-attribute-not-working-after-upgrading-facelets-to-jsf-2) that there was a documentation bug where `rendered` falsly wasn't listed in the JSF 2.0 documentation, but the response says nothing about JSF 2.2 or MyFaces 2.2 (presumably because it dates before the release of JSF 2.2).

Is the missing `rendered` attribute in the MyFaces documentation also just a bug?

With multiple such occurances of the `ui:fragment` element in a single Facelets file, these "false" errors make finding real errors quite cumbersome. What is the recommended solution for this problem, if it really is just a bug in the documentation?

Comment: Since I began working with JSF 2 (5 years ago right now) I have faced this situation. The attribute definitelly works, but the IDEs don't consider it (nor Intellij or Eclipse). Seems to be a documentation error that has been ported to 2.1 and 2.2 by the IDE parsers. The attribute is definitelly there in 2.1 docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/3714063#3714063 Don't know in MyFaces.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanks for the comment. Ok, then I will just continue to use the `rendered` attribute. It just concerns me a little that the this documentation bug got fixed in the Mojarra documentation (since version 2.1?), but not in the MyFaces 2.2 documentation.

Comment: There's a line in the errata list about this in the JSF 2.2 spec from march 2013. The link is http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_2-fr-eval-spec/index.html and it is in the page 406 of the pdf document (C114): `Add "rendered" attribute to VDL docs for ui:component and 
ui:fragment.`. So MyFaces seems not to have properly updated this part too.

Answer (score 0):

`rendered` is valid attribute in `ui:fragment` and `ui:component` in JSF 2.0, 2.1, 2.2. See [JSF 2.2 View Declaration Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/toc.htm).

Some IDEs do not propose this attribute in autocomplete (content assistant) mode and validate it as "Unknown attribute". This happens because the `rendered` attribute was missing in the tag file declaration in JSF 2.0 (even if attribute was presented in the UIComponent) and the IDE validation is based on the tag file declarations. Issue was fixed in JSF 2.1: the missing attribute was added into the tag file declaration. Validation in IDE not always reflect to this change.

Comment: @Kukeltje The `rendered` attribute was missing in the tag file declaration in JSF 2.0, but was presented in the UIComponent. The IDE validation is based on the tag file declarations and it gives a misleading validation warning/error. This issue was fixed in JSF 2.1, the missing attribute was added to the tag file declaration.