# JSF Component without own HTML element

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am looking for a JSF 2.0 Component that is just an container for other components but do not produce own HTML elements.

My situation is that I have an (already styled) jsf-xhtml component page. Now I need to disable a lot of the rendering.

```
<ui:component>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">...</>
</ui:component>
```

But I do not want to specify the `rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}"` fore times. Instead I want to wrapp it with some component like:

```
<ui:component>
    <xxxx  rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    </xxxx>
</ui:component>
```

Because the page is already styled (and I fear that this is done in a fragile way) I need an jsf-component (`xxxx`) that does NOT produce own html elements like `div` or so.
Does such an jsf-component exit?

Comment: Just remove `layout="block"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">
```

http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html

Comment: This was the element I was looking for, anywaz this Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3713468/280244 prevents me from using `ui:fragment`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using primefaces then you have a simple solution:

use `p:outputPanel`.

If not, then you can also use `h:panelGroup`. This does not have any formatting of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:if test="#{not empty user.registrations}">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
</c:if>
```

or you can wrap your 4 `<h:panelGroup>` with another `<h:panelGroup>`:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty user.registrations}">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">...</>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I do not think that `c:if` is allowed in JSF 2.0 Facelets

Comment: @Ralph: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense