# Conditionally displaying a block of HTML based on presence of resource bundle key

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf, facelets

I'm using JSF, and I have to load a bundle called Extra.

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.ni.lib.extra.delivery.ExtraBundle" var="extra" />
```

Inside that extra variable, there's a value called downtime_notice. Now, if that value is NOT empty, I have to show a css segment with the text contained within the downtime_notice value. Something like this (of course this doesn't work):

```
if(extra.donwtime_notice!=''){
            <div class="pnx-msg pnx-msg-warning clearfix">
                <i class="pnx-msg-icon pnx-icon-msg-warning"/>
                <span class="pnx-msg-content"><h:outputText value="#{extra.downtime_notice}" escape="false"/></span>
            </div>
            </br>
}
```

I can use javascript, just in case.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<ui:fragment>` or `<h:panelGroup>` to conditionally render content. You can use the `empty` keyword in EL to check if a variable is not null or empty. So, all with all this should do:

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty extra.donwtime_notice}">
    <div class="pnx-msg pnx-msg-warning clearfix">
        <i class="pnx-msg-icon pnx-icon-msg-warning"/>
        <span class="pnx-msg-content"><h:outputText value="#{extra.downtime_notice}" escape="false"/></span>
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Or, using `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` which renders a `<div>` already:

```html
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="pnx-msg pnx-msg-warning clearfix" rendered="#{not empty extra.donwtime_notice}">
    <i class="pnx-msg-icon pnx-icon-msg-warning"/>
    <span class="pnx-msg-content"><h:outputText value="#{extra.downtime_notice}" escape="false"/></span>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that some may opt to use `<f:verbatim>` for the job, but this tag is *deprecated* since JSF2.

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557)
- [Alternative to ui:fragment in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/3714063#3714063)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `</br>` tag is invalid HTML, so I omitted it form the examples.

Comment: Works perfectly. Just one more question, to avoid creating another thread... I'm trying to compare the downtime_notice value to a ' '. I've been trying to use something like rendered="#{extra.downtime_notice ne ' '}" but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Properties file values are by default trimmed. So you need something else. Perhaps `_`?

Comment: For some reason, it's returning an error. The code looks like this: <ui:fragment rendered="#{extra.downtime_notification ne '?'}">. Maybe the ne clause doesn't work for the ui:fragment?