# Why <h:panelGroup> id is not found when I access through <f:subview> tag?

Tags: jsf-2

```
 <h:panelGroup id="userPanel"><f:subview rendered="#{searchView.isUser}">
    <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{searchAction.doFindUsers}"   >
        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" render="userPanel" />
    </h:commandButton> </f:subview></h:panelGroup>
```

I am getting the error as: cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `<f:subview>` is a [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html).

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)

---

Just use `<h:panelGroup>`,

```
<h:panelGroup id="userPanel">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchView.isUser}">
        <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{searchAction.doFindUsers}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" render="userPanel" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

or `<ui:fragment>` (which has only a little less overhead)

```
<h:panelGroup id="userPanel">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{searchView.isUser}">
        <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{searchAction.doFindUsers}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" render="userPanel" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

or in this specific example just directly on command button (surely your case is more complex than that)

```
<h:panelGroup id="userPanel">
    <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{searchAction.doFindUsers}"  rendered="#{searchView.isUser}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" render="userPanel" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Alternative to ui:fragment in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/)
- [Conditional rendering of non-JSF components (plain vanilla HTML and template text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946985/the-right-way-to-conditional-rendering-of-non-jsf-components/)