# Why is ui:fragement not rendered inside ui:composition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, templating

I'm a beginner with JSF and Java, please be nice!

I'm trying to render a specific block if a user is an Administrator.

I have a template. This template render correctly a specific block if the user is logged.

admin.xhtml:

```
    <ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/tpl/admin/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="sectionTitle">Admin</ui:define>

        <!-- Logged as Admin -->
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{user.admin}">
            <ui:define name="body">
                <h3>Welcome</h3>
                <p>Please choose an administration task!</p>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:fragment>

    </ui:composition>
```

template.xhtml:

```
<div class="header">
    <h2>
        <ui:insert name="sectionTitle"> Default Section Title</ui:insert>
    </h2>
    <ui:insert name="logBox">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{not user.logged}">
            <ui:include src="login.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:fragment>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{user.logged}">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton value="Logout"
                    action="#{userService.logout}" />
            </h:form>
        </ui:fragment>
    </ui:insert>
</div>

    <div class="corebody">
        <ui:insert name="body"> Default Section Content</ui:insert>
    </div>
```

I can move the rendered block inside the template like so:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{user.admin}">
        <ui:insert name="body"> Default Section Content</ui:insert>
</ui:fragment>
```

but this don't seem ok to me regarding the responsability of each files ( this don't seem really generic, why should such a thing be in the template? ).

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: This [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything outside `<ui:define>` and `<ui:composition>` is **ignored** during building the view and don't end up in JSF component tree.

You need to put `<ui:fragment>` inside `<ui:define>`.

```
<ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/tpl/admin/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="sectionTitle">Admin</ui:define>

    <!-- Logged as Admin -->
    <ui:define name="body">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{user.admin}">
            <h3>Welcome</h3>
            <p>Please choose an administration task!</p>
        </ui:fragment>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

An alternative is to use JSTL `<c:if>` as that runs during view build time already:

```
<ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/tpl/admin/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="sectionTitle">Admin</ui:define>

    <!-- Logged as Admin -->
    <c:if test="#{user.admin}">
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h3>Welcome</h3>
            <p>Please choose an administration task!</p>
        </ui:define>
    </c:if>

</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: @BasluC: I'm trying to follow your example with JSTL and it's not working :(. I'm working with JSF1.2, could it be that? I already tried with different namespaces.

Comment: I already asked a question that no one answered about a week ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810854/jsf-1-2-dynamic-uiparam

Comment: @Gabriel: use [jsf] tag to get attention from JSF users, not only a version tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/tpl/admin/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="sectionTitle">

        <!-- Logged as Admin -->
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{user.admin}">
            <ui:define name="body">
                 <h3>Welcome</h3>
                 <p>Please choose an administration task!</p>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:fragment>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Try this.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, but moving the ui:fragment in a the body ui:define is ok.

Comment: This construct isn't making any sense.