# JSF 1.2: dynamic <ui:param />

Tags: jsf, parameters, conditional-statements, facelets, jsf-1.2

There are some answers on stackoverflow, but no one fits my needs :(

I'm trying to conditionally build a `<ui:param />` for my parent template with JSTL. Something like this:

```
<ui:composition ... template="template.xhtml">

    <c:if test="#{condition}">
        <ui:param name="parameter" value="parameterValue" />
    </c:if>

    <ui:define name="insertName">
        {...}
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

I tried with both namespaces for JSTL: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core and http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core, but neither achieves the wanted behaviour. What should I do?

Funny thing, http://java.sun.com/jstl/core works like it should but **INSIDE** the `<ui:define ...>`

Im working with JSF 1.2 on WebLogic 7.

Comment: When is `#{condition}` set? Problem suggests it's set by `template.xhtml` itself which would be too late. An alternative would be to use `<ui:param value="#{condition ? parameterValue : null}">`.

Comment: #{condition} is read from bean. I tested that the values are correct displaying them in <ui:define>. I didn't want to use ternary operator as I set multiple <ui:param> that depend on multiple conditions: it will end looking ugly and bloated. I understand JSTL should work here, I just can't get why it doesnt :(

Comment: I also tried with #{true} and #{false}