# Update of a conditionally rendered selectItem not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm wondering why updating a form won't update a conditionally rendered selectItem. The commandButton (for testing purposes) is updated correctly as expected.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectedGroupId" label="#{msgs.group_group}" value="#{groupBean.selectedGroupId}">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{groupBean.selectGroupEvent}" update=":form"/>
        <f:selectItem rendered="#{empty groupBean.selectedGroupId}" itemLabel="#{msgs.global_select_select}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{groupBean.availableGruppen}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   <p:commandButton value="Test" actionListener="#{groupBean.test}" rendered="#{empty groupBean.selectedGroupId}"/> 
</h:form>
```

Any hints what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks
Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `rendered` attribute for `f:selectItem`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932217/620338), you can use a `<c:if>` as a wrapper instead or modify your list of `f:selecItems` in your action method.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer. I'm using MyFaces 2.1.7 and there is a rendered attribute for UISelectItem.  `public class UISelectItem extends javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase
{
...
    //BEGIN CODE COPIED FROM javax.faces.component._UISelectItem 
    public void setRendered(boolean state)
    {
        super.setRendered(state);
        ...
    }` Or am I wrong again? Jonny

Comment: And by the way: The <c:if> worked like a charm (but I still want to use the rendered attribute, if there is one). Thanks a lot Matt

Comment: Ok, I looked into Mojarra api doc. So this is different somehow.

Comment: I also desperately need a property like itemRendered for f:selectItem. But it seems most experts want to achieve it in the backing controller, but I still think it is a very useful attribute. I have posted a link hear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611620/filter-values-in-fselectitems-in-jsf-primefaces?noredirect=1#comment25670995_17611620