# How to internationalize selectOneMenu drop down items which recived from DataBase in JSF?

Tags: jsf, internationalization, selectonemenu

I need Internationalize items for the selectOneMenu JSF component. How can it be done for the List which received from database?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="action" value="#{mapBean.newAction}" style="width:150px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Action" itemValue="Empty"
                            noSelectionOption="false" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{mapBean.actions}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

For the mapBean.actions I need dinamicaly change values according selected language
For now I don't have an idea how implement this.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4375578

Comment: As I understood in this article values came from ENUM's, but my idea put values in the database. For example create table action that contains  value and different locales('en','uk','ru'). According selected locale retrieve new values for the  selectOneMenu. I just want to work with database for values, not using propertis files.

Comment: Oh? Those localized values come from database itself? In other words, those localized values are already inside `#{mapBean.actions}`? Then I'm not understanding anymore why you're having a problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood your question you have list of objects with "Locale" property. And you want to display only items with specified locale in your selectOneMenu. You can do something like this to filter selectItems:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="action" value="#{mapBean.newAction}" style="width:150px">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Action" itemValue="Empty"
                                noSelectionOption="false" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{mapBean.actions}" 
                                var="item" itemDisabled="#{item.locale ne 'en'}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And add this to css to your page to not display disabled items:

```
.ui-selectlistbox-item.ui-state-disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

This is solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17634618/6065134)