# Passing data to a JSF facelet

Tags: jsf, jstl

On the 1st page that is displayed in my JSF application, I want to display data from a database in the form of a table. I have a ManagedBean called a ProductList which has an ArrayList of Product Objects, and I want to put all the Products in a table. I am using the jstl c:forEach tags, but for some reason I get a compile error:

Fatal Error: The prefix "c" for element "c:forEach" is not bound.

Am I using the forEach tag correctly?

```
<c:forEach items="#{productList.allProducts}" var="product">

</c:forEach>
```

Here are the namespace tags:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

Comment: Can you show the namespace definitions? It is the `html` tag, with all the `xmlns` attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define all the namespaces(the `h:`, `f:`prefixes of your xml tags) that you use in the page.

The proper definition for `xmlns:c` is `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`

You can have a longer example here: [<c:if test> seems to always evaluate true in JSF2 Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335670/cif-test-is-not-being-invoked-in-facelet-jsf2)